# How do I remove the unused zeros from a date formatted like "0d 0h 23m 4s"?

Tags: javascript, date-formatting

How do I remove the unused zeros from my website counter, when it says 0d 0h 23m 4s... the "0d" & "0h" should be removed... How do I do this?

**Below is a copy of my code,** it works I just don't know how to stop the zeros from showing when it's not needed. example: the timer reads.. **0d 0h 58m 3s...** the days and hoursare at  **Zero** and **dont need to be shown** so how do I remove them? I hope this  gives you a clear picture of what the situation here is.

```
var year=2012    //-->Enter the count down target date YEAR
var month=3      //-->Enter the count down target date MONTH
var day=27       //-->Enter the count down target date DAY
var hour=0      //-->Enter the count down target date HOUR (24 hour clock)
var minute=00    //-->Enter the count down target date MINUTE
var tz=-5        //-->Offset for your timezone in hours from UTC (see http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/index.htm to find the timezone offset for your location)

//    -->DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW! This is just a personal comment dont mind it<--
var montharray=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")

function countdown(yr,m,d,hr,min){
theyear=yr;themonth=m;theday=d;thehour=hr;theminute=min
    var today=new Date()
    var todayy=today.getYear()
    if (todayy < 1000) {todayy+=1900}
    var todaym=today.getMonth()
    var todayd=today.getDate()
    var todayh=today.getHours()
    var todaymin=today.getMinutes()
    var todaysec=today.getSeconds()
    var todaystring1=montharray[todaym]+" "+todayd+", "+todayy+" "+todayh+":"+todaymin+":"+todaysec
    var todaystring=Date.parse(todaystring1)+(tz*1000*60*60)
    var futurestring1=(montharray[m-1]+" "+d+", "+yr+" "+hr+":"+min);
    var futurestring=Date.parse(futurestring1)-(today.getTimezoneOffset()*(1000*60));
    var dd=futurestring-todaystring
    var dday=Math.floor(dd/(60*60*1000*24)*1)
    var dhour=Math.floor((dd%(60*60*1000*24))/(60*60*1000)*1)
    var dmin=Math.floor(((dd%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))/(60*1000)*1)
    var dsec=Math.floor((((dd%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))%(60*1000))/1000*1)
    if(dday<=0&&dhour<=0&&dmin<=0&&dsec<=0){
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=current;
        return;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=+dday+ "d "+dhour+"h "+dmin+"m "+dsec+"s";
        setTimeout("countdown(theyear,themonth,theday,thehour,theminute)",1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line:

```
document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=+dday+ "d "+dhour+"h "+dmin+"m "+dsec+"s";
```

to conditionally show the dday, dhour etc. For example:

```
document.getElementById('count').innerHTML= ((dday !=0) ? (dday+ "d ") : "") + ((dhour !=0) ? dhour+"h " : "") +dmin+"m "+dsec+"s";
```

For more clarity, you can build the string in multiple lines, as such:

```
var counterStr = "";
if (dday != 0)
  counterStr += dday+ "d ";
if (dhour != 0)
  counterStr += dday + "h ";
counterStr += dmin+"m "+dsec+"s";

document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = counterStr;
```

Comment: U da man!, U da man! - I just copied and pasted the first line of code you told me to re place and the zeros just vanished... Do I need to do anything more... in general or with that part you told me about "for more clarity" or was that another example/ way you were showing me how to do it, or do I need to use that code?  -  Thanks "Tech Lover" Steve

Answer (score 1):

replacing it with empty string an idea?

```
document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=current.replace(/0[a-z]\s/gi,'');
```

and whilst counting:

```
document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=
                 (+dday > 0 ? +dday + 'd ' : '') +
                 (dhour > 0 ? dhour+'h ' : '') +
                 (dmin > 0 ? dmin+'m ' : '') +
                  dsec+'s';
```

or (shorter)

```
var val = +dday+ "d "+dhour+"h "+dmin+"m "+dsec+"s";
document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = val.replace(/0[a-z]\s/gi,'');
```

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. (Jwz)

Comment: Ah well, there's a non regex solution in the answer too ... Could you elaborate on the two problems?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    else {
count_str = "";
if (dday > 0) {
count_str = count_str + dday + "d ";
}
if (dhour> 0) {
count_str = count_str + dhour + "h ";
}
count_str = count_str + dmin+"m "+dsec+"s"
document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=count_str;
        setTimeout("countdown(theyear,themonth,theday,thehour,theminute)",1000);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Don't break your sweat on something which is already taken care of by [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). This tiny javascript library with no dependencies takes care of displaying date or time (elapsed till now). It also has robust support for localization.

Comment: Can we keep it to answering the questions as they were asked?